# SQLite insert row make undefined error

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova

I try to insert a row with SQLite on iPhone.

```
DB.query('INSERT INTO documents (title, anything, largeImage, author, isbn) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', [ 'title', 'jgfu', 'mop', 'author', 40 ]);
```

with this scheme :

```
    {
        name: 'documents',
        columns: [
            {name: 'id', type: 'integer primary key'},
            {name: 'title', type: 'text'},
            {name: 'anything', type: 'text'},
            {name: 'author', type: 'text'},
            {name: 'isbn', type: 'integer'},
            {name: 'largeImage', type: 'text'},
            {name: 'bookType', type: 'text'}
        ]
    }
```

And SQLite doesn't work.

When I Write this code :

```
DB.query('INSERT INTO documents (title, largeImage, author, isbn) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', [ 'title', 'mop', 'author', 40 ]);
```

is OK!
I try to invert cols, values, col's type. It's the same, doesn't work.The error seems like aleatory.
Anybody know what's happen?

---

EDIT :
I think this is this second cols have a problem {name: 'anything', type: 'text'}, Corrupt??

Comment: I don't know, I haven't error and I haven't no insert

Comment: I faced the same error my last insertID was returning undefined and in my case the problem was that the table wasn't created yet , while trying to insert.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is very picky about names, it is a best practice to escape names in SQLite statements.

```
DB.query('INSERT INTO `documents` (`title`, `anything`, `largeImage`, `author`, `isbn`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', [ 'title', 'jgfu', 'mop', 'author', 40 ]);
```

Comment: Nothing more. Title can be something like this "string string string", space can generate an error?

Comment: Spaces and reserved words. That is why I always escape. If you needa  field called `key` or `value` anything that is a reserved word in SQLite will break the query if the don't escape it.

Comment: I have more news. I work on OSx and on ubuntu too, and on ubuntu I have no error, insert is ok. Can I think .db is corrupt?